# redirect location to docker registry port

Tags: apache, nexus, httpd.conf, docker-registry

I setup a Docker registry in my Nexus with https connector on port 8123. I can successfully login to it:

```
docker login nexus.myserver.com:8123
```

But my goal is to use custom paths instead of port numbers, for example:

```
docker login nexus.myserver.com/myregistry1
```

So I tried to configure my apache conf like this:

```
Redirect /myregistry1 http://127.0.0.1:8123
ProxyPass /myregistry1 http://127.0.0.1:8123
ProxyPassReverse /myregistry1 http://127.0.0.1:8123
```

But when I try to login (`docker login nexus.myserver.com/myregistry1`), I get:

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://nexus.myserver.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

I'm not very familiar with apache, so any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may set server port on conf file.
Or both ports are using, then please add both ports on conf file.

Like this.

Listen 8123
Listen 80

You installed your site on 8123 port. so calling to 80 port returns 404 error.